# How can I show a custom exception message in visual studio test explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a custom exception class

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    string moreInfo;
    public CustomException(string message, string info) : base(message)
    {
        moreInfo = info;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Custom Exception Info:" + moreInfo;
    }
}
```

This can be thrown inside a Test so I get the following message:

[image]

Is there a way to show more info inside the Test Explorer (Without modifing the Message property)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            throw new CustomException("aaa", "bla bla");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
All my tests work fine and I have proper Assert statements.
If for some reason though any tests are broken I don't see a meaningful error in the Test Explorer, so I have to wrap each test in a try/catch and debug them one by one manually...

It's seems silly having to do that since I have all the error info I need at the time the exception is thrown

Comment: I totally agree, and I wish I had the answer. Test Explorer is virtually useless, even if you have the message in Assert.XXX, you still only see "NUnit.Framework.AssertionException : Exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' was thrown.". I use NCrunch because of this and many other short-comings (it comes with its own flaws, but is certainly many times better, and no, I'm not affiliated).