# Why doesn't the VS Test Explorer show my C++ custom exception message?

Tags: c++, exception

I've implemented a custom exception in my C++ code:

```
class LicenseFileNotPresent : public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string message = "license.json not found in %APPDATA/XXX/ or file is not populated.";
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

However, when I run a test using VS2019's Test Explorer, and this exception is thrown (by a unit test which is not intended to cause this exception), I get an unhelpful result:

> Message:
> Unhandled C++ Exception

I expected that this message would instead read:

> Message:
> license.json not found in %APPDATA/XXX/ or file is not populated.

I've read a few other posts which don't answer my question:
[C++ custom exception message not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990407/c-custom-exception-message-not-displaying)
[How can I show a custom exception message in visual studio test explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766950/how-can-i-show-a-custom-exception-message-in-visual-studio-test-explorer)

1. I'm not returning a string that goes out of scope after the `what()` function returns
2. I'm not trying to test this exception in this case, so a try/catch is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The error message suggests you are not catching your exception type. Please show us your `try/catch` code.

Comment: @jkb That's correct, I am not catching it, and I don't plan on adding try/catch code. I'm asking why the 'Test Detail Summary' in the Test Explorer shows a generic exception message rather than my specific message.

Comment: Because handing C++ exceptions is hard unless you write try/catch SOMEWHERE and COMPILE IT along with your code. Unless your unit-test suite wraps your test cases with try-catch'es automatically, which will handle std::exceptions and extract ::what(), a generic runner may only notice post-mortem that some non-SEH non-managed exception was thrown. But considering that in C++ you can `throw "foo"`, `throw (void*)"foo"`, or even `throw 1;`, I am not surprised that the test runner doesn't try inspecting the exception's payload any further.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thank you - I believe that answers my question. If VS isn't trying to show my message due to the complexity of handling exceptions, this would make sense.

Comment: (continuing) For example, unit test suites like GTEST (Google Test) have special modes for C++ Exceptions - GTest comes with a set of macros to wrap your test case functions, and if you enable GTest's "c++ exception support" it will actually wrap your tests with try/catch and will try to extract what() when they happen. It seems that your unit testing tools don't do that.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thank you, it sounds like I was just making too many assumptions about how the VS test framework works and I was also under the mistaken impression that exception objects were more standardized.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://durwella.tumblr.com/post/96457792632/extending-microsoft-cppunittestframework#96457792632) handy if you use this framework. Note what they do in the article :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be my mistaken assumptions about where the VS test framework gets the message "Unhandled C++ Exception". I was thinking that the test executor would dive into the std::exception object to get the `what()` message, but this is not safe behavior on the part of the test framework because it can't be sure that I'm throwing a `std::exception` versus other possibilities.

The reason so many comments say things like "where is your try/catch block?" is that this is the *only way* to run unit tests that may throw exceptions, *even if the exception is not expected to be thrown by the test!*

Thanks to @queztalcoatl for the complete explanation given in the comments.